# No response from VM Scale Set

Tags: azure, docker, azure-vm-scale-set

I created a VM ScaleSet from a custom image where Docker is pre-installed. For testing, I just run on all available VMs this command: `sudo docker container run -d -p 80:80 seqvence/static-site` (just showing a simple static site on port 80).
However, I first created a healthProbe (just checking for tcp:80). Then I created a loadbalancing rule for port:80 -> backend port:80. And of course my LoadBalancer has a backend pool containing my VMs of my ScaleSet.

But when I now navigate to *myvmss.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com* I get `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

What am I missing?

Comment: network security group to allow port 80?

Comment: Hours of checking LoadBalancing configuration and the app inside my VMs.... and then you are absolutely right - it was the NSG -.- thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 80 was blocked by Network security Group.

How to allow it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pkirchner/2016/02/02/allow-incoming-web-traffic-to-web-server-in-azure-vm/